# Error when trying to create a project under a GitLab group

Tags: repository, gitlab, project

I just discovered GitLab's groups and decided that it would be ideal for the kind of work I am doing. I created a *private group* and am getting the following error when I try to create a project under it:

```
The form contains the following error:
PG::QueryCanceled: ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout CONTEXT: while rechecking updated tuple (0,187) in relation "site_statistics" : UPDATE "site_statistics" SET "repositories_count" = "repositories_count"+1
```

I attempted to do the same in a new subgroup; however, I still get the same error. I must add that I am not using a paid plan of GitLab.

Thank you.

Comment: Update: I kept trying to create the project and I got the error several times until the project was finally created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. I think only thing that we can to do is to wait until this error will fix.

Found this issue page: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53778

Comment: Please read the update I just added. Also, kindly delete this as it is not really an answer to the question. Thank you and best regards.

Comment: The answer is that you currently cant create new projects at all. You need to wait while gitlab-devs fix this problem. It is a global common problem